# The value of $ A \exp\left(\frac{-1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \ln(1+A+2BC \cos x) dx \right)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration

I'm looking for the value of: $$ A \exp\left(\frac{-1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \ln(1+A+2BC \cos x) dx \right)$$ 
I know we could take $y=1+A+2BC \cos x$ but changing variable in this way makes the integral from $1+ A - 2BC$ to $1+ A - 2BC$ which makes the integral zero!
How to solve it ?
thanks

Comment: $\cos$ is an even function, so the integral is $2\int_0^\pi \dotsb$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:$$y=A \exp\left(\frac{-1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \ln(1+A+2BC \cos x) \  \mathrm dx \right)\to$$
$$\ln y=\ln A+\left(\frac{-1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \ln(1+A+2BC \cos x  \mathrm dx\right)=\ln A+\left(\frac{-1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln(1+A+2BC \cos x  \mathrm dx \right)$$
now take $1+A+2BC \cos x=z$ then $\  \mathrm dz=-2BC\ \sin x \ \mathrm dx\to \  \mathrm dx=\pm \dfrac{-\  \mathrm dz}{2BC\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ we have

$$\ln y=\ln A-\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi BC} \left(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{-\ln z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \  \mathrm dz+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \frac{\ln z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \  \mathrm dz\right) }_H
$$
then integrate by part ...$$\large{y '=Ae^{H}\cdot H '}$$